# Declare dynamic object name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim rptDocument As New ReportDocument
If Request.QueryString("rpt") = "rptTest" Then
    rptDocument = New rptTest
ElseIf Request.QueryString("rpt") = "rptMain" Then
    rptDocument = New rptMain
ElseIf Request.QueryString("rpt") = "rptLast" Then
    rptDocument = New rptLast
...
End If
```

Change to

```
rptDocument = New Request.QueryString("rpt")
```

The query string data will be match the object name. How to dynamic declare this variable?

Comment: Does `rptTest`, `rptMain` and `rptLast` classes inherit from `ReportDocument` class? Your current structure reminds of factory-method design pattern.

Comment: rptTest, rptMain and rptLast is the crystal report embedded resource. What I want is every time include new report without create if else statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining reference to Class instance by string name - VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434530/obtaining-reference-to-class-instance-by-string-name-vb-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic: dynamically create objects using a string as the name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3432317/11683)

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer

Comment: but I have another issue posted on

Comment: You should not post questions as answers @MayWong, please delete it. The second linked question shows you what to do when the type is in another assembly.