# String form name to form reference

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Basically, I am rewriting some code working for years. Over the time I have many (60+) references to forms - there's a menuitem with OnClick event for each form, where a form reference was created:

```
Private Sub SomeForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItemForSomeForm.Click
    NewTab("Some Form", New SomeForm, 0)
End Sub
```

...where first parameter is a name to put in a tabPage.Text where the form is opened, second is a new instance of the (particular) form SomeForm and 0 is a default record to display (0 means no default record).

Now, I created a dynamic menu and stored the form names in a database (due to better access control over the access rights, etc). Now, because the menu is generated at runtime, I can't have the OnClick event with separate instance definition of the form and have to create it at runtime, after the MenuItems are created. The side-effect idea was to cut the code short by using only 1 OnClick event or such with MenuItem.Tag paremeter as FormName. Something like:

```
Private Sub clickeventhandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim tsmi As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim newForm As New >>>FormFrom(tsmi.Tag.ToString)<<<  ' only explanation, this won't work
MainW.OpenModuleInTab(new newForm, tsmi.Tag.ToString, 0)
```

However I am failing to find a way to create form (instances) from this string reference. Reference through collection (i.e. List(of) or Dictionary) would be fine too, I believe.

The structure is obviously:

Object → Form → Form1 (class) → MyForm1 (instance)

I know I can create an object like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434530/obtaining-reference-to-class-instance-by-string-name-vb-net):

```
' Note that you are getting a NEW instance of MyClassA
Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(NameOfMyClass))
```

I can re-type it to a Form type:

```
Dim NewForm as Form = CType(MyInstance,Form)
```

... to acccess some of the form properties like Width, TopLevel, etc., but that's about it. I can't do:

```
Dim NewForm1 as Form1 = CType(NewForm,Form1)
```

...because obviously, Form1 comes as a string "Form1".

I don't know how to create a Form1 reference from a "Form1" text (then it would be easy to create an instance) or how to create an instance directly (MyForm1).

**SOLUTION**

As sugested, I used reflection to get the form. The only way working for me I found was this:

```
    Dim T As Type = System.Type.GetType(FormName, False) 
    If T Is Nothing Then 'if not found prepend default namespace
        Dim Fullname As String = Application.ProductName & "." & FormName
        T = System.Type.GetType(Fullname, True, True)
    End If

    Dim f2 As New Form   ' here I am creating a form and working with it
    f2 = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(T), Form)
    f2.TopLevel = False
    f2.Name = FormName.Replace(" ", "") & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmmhh")
    f2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

I am using VB.net CallByName to set public variable and same function to run a sub method (every form contains RecordID variable and LoadRecords sub):

```
    CallByName(f2, "RecordID", CallType.Set, 111)
    CallByName(f2, "LoadRecords", CallType.Method, Nothing)
```

For testing purposes, I put following into the testing form:

```
Public RecordID As Int32
Public Sub LoadRecords()
    MsgBox("Load records!!!!" & vbCrLf & "RecordID = " & RecordID)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you do it from a string then you must know what assembly it lives in, so you can call Assembly.Load(), and the namespace it is declared in, so you can call Assembly.GetType().

Comment: The code you've shown is exactly how you would do this. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Fabio oh I forgot to mention that - this works only on Object and maybe Form, not a Form1 object. Possibly might work under some circumstances (assembly reference), where I humbly admit a big knowledge gap...

Comment: @Enigmativity - do you mean CType? You need object reference to retype the object, and I have only a string reference. GetType() won't work for a Form1 class, it would only work for an Object.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 - You can't turn a **run-time** string into a **compile-time** type. But you can use reflection to call methods, for example, that take an object of the type you have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's go with the idea that I have an assembly called "WindowsApp2" and in that assembly I've defined `Form1` and `Form2`. I've also created this module in the same assembly:

```
Public Module Module1

    Public Function GetDoStuffWiths() As Dictionary(Of Type, System.Delegate)
        Dim DoStuffWiths As New Dictionary(Of Type, System.Delegate)()
        DoStuffWiths.Add(GetType(WindowsApp2.Form1), CType(Sub(f) WindowsApp2.Module1.DoStuffWithForm1(f), Action(Of WindowsApp2.Form1)))
        DoStuffWiths.Add(GetType(WindowsApp2.Form2), CType(Sub(f) WindowsApp2.Module1.DoStuffWithForm2(f), Action(Of WindowsApp2.Form2)))
        Return DoStuffWiths
    End Function

    Public Sub DoStuffWithForm1(form1 As Form1)
        form1.Text = "This is Form 1"
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoStuffWithForm2(form2 As Form2)
        form2.Text = "This is Form 2"
    End Sub

End Module
```

Now, in another assembly "ConsoleApp1" I write this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim DoStuffWiths As Dictionary(Of Type, System.Delegate) = WindowsApp2.Module1.GetDoStuffWiths()

    Dim formAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("WindowsApp2")
    Dim typeOfForm = formAssembly.GetType("WindowsApp2.Form1")

    Dim form As Form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfForm), Form)

    DoStuffWiths(typeOfForm).DynamicInvoke(form)

    Application.Run(form)

End Sub
```

When I run my console app I get a form popping up with the message `"This is Form 1"`.

If I change the line `formAssembly.GetType("WindowsApp2.Form1")` to `formAssembly.GetType("WindowsApp2.Form2")` then I get the message `"Wow this is cool"`.

That's how you can work with strongly typed objects that you dynamically instantiate.

Comment: I will look into this solution, however it seems to me it crates some hard coded definitions to the form instances and the ida is to get rid of them. Currently, I have an OnClick event at each button and a line which calls a NewTab(FormName, "Form Caption", RecordID). I.e. 3 lines per form, but I have tons of forms...

Comment: @Oak_3260548 - You can use reflection to remove the hard-coded references, but this kind of thing is only way to get compile-time references to dynamically created instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(TypeFromName("Form1"))
```

TypeFromName Function:

```
Dim list As Lazy(Of Type()) = New Lazy(Of Type())(Function() Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())

Function TypeFromName(name As String) As Type
    Return list.Value.Where(Function(t) t.Name = name).FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

Comment: This seems pretty close, however I struggle to implement it. Please pardon my lack of knowledge. Dim list gives me option strict error (required As Type definition), but if it is not achievable, I could turn option strict off on one class and still be reasonably safe. The activator should be called every time a reference is created, right? So i.e. in OnClick, I'd call Activator and then CType(Form,TypeFromName("Form1")), correct?

Comment: `CType(Form,TypeFromName("Form1"))` - does not ever work.

Comment: @Enigmativity, true.

Comment: @lomed - The built-in method `Type.GetType` already does what your function does.

Comment: @Enigmativity how GetType return type from string?

Comment: Well, I guess you do need the `AssemblyQualifiedName`.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, I tested a lot and cannot get to Form1 object. Maybe a silly question, but how would you use the Activator.CrateInstance code? I'd assume it would create an instance of the Form1, but then I fail to grasp this instance...

Comment: @Oak_3260548 Your desire is illogical: on one hand, you want refer  the instance in design time as Form1, On the other hand you do not want to point to it explicitly but you leave it open for running time. i think you need edit your uestion and exsplain what is your need in the **bottom line**, which is why you are in this trouble

Comment: Well I thought I explained the bottom line, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'll try to modify it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim AssemblyProduct As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName.Name
    Dim FormName As String = "Form1"

    Dim NewForm As Object = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CreateInstance(AssemblyProduct & "." & FormName)

    If TypeOf (NewForm) Is Form1 Then
        Dim NewForm1 As Form1 = CType(NewForm, Form1)
        NewForm1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
        NewForm1.Show()
    End If
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know that the type is `Form1` at compile-time.

Comment: A simple IF check... seems valid to me.

Comment: If the type is known at compile time then a `New Form1` could be called - it kind of defeats the purpose.